# How to access GPS location without internet

Tags: gps, web-server, tcpip

I need to provide a basic geolocation service for my clients. I built a location service based on the phone geolocation. It works great, not a problem. My problem is that some of my clients don't have an internet connection.

I know there is a company like Geotab that can provide these types of services.

If I want to build my own (very basic one), how can I make my DIY (Arduino based) GPS communicate with my web servers?

Comment: If you want communication with servers you will need internet, what you can do is use some wireless communication protocol take data at the at the gateway and then send the data on the web servers

Comment: It is possible to derive approximate locations of users from the WIFI they're currently using, but that requires a big database, such as what google has. Unlikely you can do something similar in an own project. The same applies for locating using IP addresses, which on top of it gives only very broad results.

Comment: "some of my clients doesn't have internet connection." - As you want to send data to webservers on the internet, you need to get a connection to the internet. Please explain more about the circumstances. Is the "geolocation service", that you want to provide limited to a specific area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send data to a server on the internet, you will need an internet connection, or at least a connection to a internet gateway.

Which type of connection you use, and how you set up that connection, depends on distance, speed, and coverage you need.

Probably the most universal for your application, in the sense that it will work wherever a phone would work, is to use a GSM/GPS module with an Arduino. You can google around for such modules; there are many. Note that you will need a SIM card for every module you use.

The GSM-bit of the module can then be used as a modem to communicate with your server over TCP/IP. There are many examples showing how to do that on the interwebs, so I won't go there.

If this doesn't help you enough, please add more detail to your question and I will edit the answer.